# Solr Query Syntax exact match

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field configured like

```
    <fieldType name="gtext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <!--Needed for efficient trailling wildcard queries-->
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
         maxPosAsterisk="2" maxPosQuestion="1" minTrailing="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            stemEnglishPossessive="1"               
            catenateAll="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                stemEnglishPossessive="1"               
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

So when I search for example **fun**, it will also return **funny**. How can I avoid this behavior and have only fun matched? Is it because of reverse wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is cause of the [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) filter

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
```

EdgeNGramFilterFactory generates edge grams for the token e.g.

`funny` would generate -> `f, fu, fun, funn, funny .....`

So when you search for `fun`, documents with `funny` would match

[ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory) does not cause this issue, it will only enhance the prefix query search.

for e.g. `funny` would be stored as `ynnuf`

And prefix queries `*nny` would be converted to `ynn*` which is more good for performance.

Comment: Are you sure? ngram filter is supposed to make trailing wildcard queries more efficient. Shall I get rid of it?

Comment: you need ngram for wildcards and revere for prefix queries. However, the issues mentioned by you is cause of ngrams as it would cause partial matches as well. You can use different fields with and without ngrams. w/o will not cause partial matches.